# Making bivariate proportional symbol map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, cartography, color, visualisation

I have data on two characteristics for a particular variable, say volume and quality. I want to plot these using proportional symbol map in QGIS. For Volume, I could plot using: `Symbology -> Graduated -> value (Volume) + Method (Size)`.

But if I want to show the quality by colour, say the best quality in green, medium in yellow and bad quality in red. How to plot a bivariate map in QGIS?

For example, I have following data:

[image]

Comment: How about adding labels? Can you provide some exemplary data?

Comment: I tried to copy paste the data, but I came out as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to work with a `"Quality"` field directly, without creation of additional field

[image: result]

For Graduated symbology values from the field `"Value 1"` were used.

---

**References:**

- [Color Hunt > Palettes Color > Palette 281806](https://colorhunt.co/palette/281806)

Comment: This seems easier as earlier I was using 'Categorized' for plotting volume. However, since I created the numeric quality field, I used that field only for colour coding. But, by default, it was getting colours for 1.5, 2.5. Can I customize it to show colors only for 1,2 & 3?

Comment: To me it sounds like a new question on GIS SE

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401016/making-bivariate-symbol-map-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

First, code your `Quality` attribute in numerical form, using field calculator, creating a new field `q1`:

```
case 
when quality = 'low' then 1
when quality = 'medium' then 2
when quality = 'high' then 3
end
```

Than use this field with data `driven override / assistant` to set the color based on this field:

*Defining the settings in the assistant:*
[image]

*Layer styling panel:Data driven override / Opening the assistant:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got the first step. Can you elaborate second part?

Comment: I added an additional screenshot: does that help?