# Making bivariate symbol map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, cartography, visualisation

I am making a bivariate symbol map in QGIS in which, the size of the symbol depends on one variable whereas the color on other. For example, I have taken India data from https://simplemaps.com/data/in-cities and added variable `v1` ranges from `1-100` and variable `v2` ranges from `1-5`. Now, size is defined using `v1` and color using `v2`. To create map (refer [Making bivariate proportional symbol map in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398367/making-bivariate-proportional-symbol-map-in-qgis/398376#398376))

[image]

Now, for defining size, my variable takes integer values from 1-5, but the color are shown for decimal values too:

[image]

How to fix this, so that color are generated only for 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5?

Comment: Where did you find *'Symbol fill colour'*?

Comment: I suggest you set you classification mode to `natural breaks (jenks)` while using the **colour** of your layer for classification. The size can be controlled using `data defined override`. If you don't want to directly correlate size field and actual size, you may enter any valid expression in order to manually categorize your sizes into classes.

Comment: Symbology -> Graduated-> Symbol->Symbol Setting-> Simple Marker->Fill Color->Data defined override -> Assistant

Comment: I could get different colours for different values using expression. `case  when v2 = 1 then '#480032' when v2 = 2 then '#005792' when v2 = 3 then '#fc92e3' when v2 = 4 then '#f2f4c3' when v2 = 5 then '#346751' end` But is there any way to do it directly, without writing expression?